# Access violation in MASM x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm learning assembly programming and am starting to learn procedures. I have a program which prompts a user for a value, pushes all the values of a predefined array on the stack and then searches for the value in the array. when I run the code I get this error:

Access violation reading location 0x008CC000. at Line 26 where I push them onto the stack.

Here's the code

```
TITLE HW6 Q3

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array       SWORD -5, -6, -1, -10, -44, -79     
prompt      BYTE "Please input a value: ", 0
spacing     BYTE ", ", 0
string1     BYTE "The target value is, ", 0
string2     BYTE "and is located at index: ", 0
string3     BYTE "Value not found,", 0
index       BYTE ?

.code
main PROC
    ; prompt user for target value
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString            
    call ReadInt                        ;eax = entered value

    ; set up loop
    mov esi, OFFSET array
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array

    ; push the array onto the stack
L1:   push array[esi]
      add esi, TYPE array
      loop L1

    ;Search
    call Search
 exit
 main ENDP

Search PROC
mov ecx, LENGTHOF array     ; set loop counter

L2: pop ebx                     ; pop value off stack
    cmp ebx, eax                ; compare to entered value
    je valueFound
    ;if the value isn't found
    loop L2

    ;if loop finishes without finding matching value
    jmp valueNotFound

valueFound: 
    mov edx, OFFSET string1
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt               ; target value is already in eax so we dont need to mov it into eax
    mov edx, OFFSET string2
    call WriteString
    mov eax, ecx                ; move ecx into eax to display the index
    call WriteDec
    jmp next

valueNotFound:
    mov edx, OFFSET string3
    call WriteString
    mov eax, 0
    call WriteDec

 next:
     ret
 Search ENDP

 END main
```

I'm very new to programming in masm so I have no clue why this exception is being thrown so if someone could please explain why this is happening and how to fix it that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You did `array[esi]` but ESI was already a pointer to array, not 0.  You only need to the array address once, not adding to itself.

Comment: can you provide an example? I'm a bit lost on what you're saying

Comment: `push dword ptr [esi]` since ESI is a pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes so would it just be push [esi]

Comment: If MASM accepts that with a default operand-size of dword as opposed to word (16-bit), even without `array` implying an operand-size, then yes `push [esi]` would also be a valid way to write it.